# What is wrong with this context creation?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I would like to create a render context to use opengl.
The wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc) is returning true.

But for some reason OpenGL functions are ignored.

Here is the code for context creation:

```
int pixelFormat;

hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
pfd.nSize  = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
pfd.nVersion   = 1;
pfd.dwFlags    = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 32;
pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc,&pfd);
SetPixelFormat(hdc,pixelFormat,&pfd);

hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
```

And the window creation:

```
hinst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

WNDCLASSEX wnd;
memset(&wnd, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
wnd.hInstance = hinst;
wnd.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wnd.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wnd.lpszClassName = "__myGLApp__";
        wnd.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        RegisterClassEx(&wnd);

        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, 
            "__myGLApp__",
            "valami",
            WS_VISIBLE,
            xpos,
            ypos,
            width,
            height,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            hinst,
            NULL);
```

Where am going I wrong?

Comment: Re stated problem, don't know, but instead of `memset` consider writing just `WNDCLASSEX wnd = {}`. A common idiom is to write `WNDCLASSEX classinfo = {sizeof(classinfo)}`. And instead of `WS_VISIBLE` (almost never good idea for top level window), you should probably use `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` (however, I haven't tried it).

Comment: What do you mean by "OpenGL functions are ignored" ? Does glGetError() give an error code ? Just to be sure, are you calling wglSwapBuffer() after you calls to OpenGL drawing functions?

Comment: OMG, thanks. You are right, I forgot to call wglSwapBuffer().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the glGetError() function to get an error code. You can also get a textual description with the functions gluErrorString() and gluErrorUnicodStringEXT() from the utility library. Something like this:

```
char *message;
message = gluErrorString(glGetError());
printf("OpenGL error: %s\n", message);
```